# How to make my ListBox not to call SelectionChanged event, when I assign ItemSource of my list

Tags: silverlight-3.0, webservice-client

I have a combobox, that I populate from a web service:

```
public Configure()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WebServiceSoapClient ws = new WebServiceSoapClient();
        ws.GetTypesCompleted += new  EventHandler<GetTypesCompletedEventArgs>(OnGetTypeCompleted);
        ws.GetTypesAsync();
    }

    void OnGetTypeCompleted(object sender, GetTypesCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result != null)
        {
            List<CodeTableItem> source = e.Result.ToList<CodeTableItem>();
            lstType.ItemsSource = source;
            lstType.SelectedIndex = -1;

        }
    }
```

So when I set the ItemSource property, SelectionChanged event gets fired with SelectedIndex = 0, but user hasn't made this selection yet and I need this list to have no selected value, so I'm setting SelectedIndex to -1, as you can see. As a result, SelectionChanged is called twice.

Can I make it be called only when user selects the item?
Thanks!

I'm using Silverlight 3 and VS 2008

Comment: that's still a critical question... anybody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, modify your code so that the SelectionChange event handler isn't defined until after the itemssource and selected index are set.

```
void OnGetTypeCompleted(object sender, GetTypesCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result != null)
    {
        List<CodeTableItem> source = e.Result.ToList<CodeTableItem>();
        lstType.ItemsSource = source;
        lstType.SelectedIndex = -1;

        lstType.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(lstType_SelectionChanged);

    }
}
```

Comment: I think that's the easiest solution for my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: lstType.SelectionChanged -= new SelectionChangedEventHandler(lstType_SelectionChanged); lstType.SelectedIndex = -1;

        lstType.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(lstType_SelectionChanged);

Answer (score 1):

In our application we implemented some code that would set a boolean flag based on the Control.LeftMouseButtonUp() event. When this has been set, it would mean that the user has interacted with the field, and so we can handle the SelectionChanged with different behaviour.

Over the development lifetime of our application this approach was essential so that default bindings would trigger our SelectionChanged logic when we didn't want it to.

If you are an MVVM purist, you'll need to expose the VM as a member variable and then set the bool flag in the VM.

HTH,
Mark

Comment: The solution above is a bit easier for my situation, but that's a good thing to keep in mind. Thank you!